# $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(f(n))}{\log n} = a$ - Interpretation

Tags: real-analysis

Let a certain function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{N} $ such that $f(nm) = f(n) f(m)$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\log(f(n))}{\log n} = a$, where $a \in \mathbb{R}$. What gives us the limit as information here?

I know that one of these functions would be the identity function. But explicitly, I would only need an interpretation of that limit.

Comment: It means that, for very large $n$, $f(n)$ behaves like $n^{a}$.

Comment: Another possibility is $f(n)=1$.

Comment: Yes asymptotically, but are there more formal interpretation? What is the link with $f (n) / n$ for example?

Comment: You have $$\log f(n) = a\log n + o(\log n).$$ So:$$f(n)=n^a\cdot e^{o(\log n)}$$

This does *not* mean that $f(n)/n^a \to 1$. But you might be able to get better asymptotics by the $f(nm)=f(n)f(m)$ condition.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Evaluation on $m^n$, gives $$a=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{\log (f(m^n))}{\log(m^n)}=\lim_{n\to \infty}\frac{n\log(f(m))}{n\log(m)}=\frac{\log(f(m))}{\log(m)}$$ So $m^a=e^{\log(m)a}=f(m)$.

Comment: Doesn't $\log f(m)=a\log m\implies f(m)=m^a$?

Comment: Yep, last step is wrong,

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Are you intending to edit, shall I, or should we wait for the OP?

Comment: @Dr.MV Yeap! and it has been corrected! I am sorry about that.

Comment: @Chanler No worry.  And +1 for the correct result. Well done!